# For every open set $B$ in $(0,1)$ we have $A∩B$ is not empty

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ be a non empty dense set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) in the open interval $(0,1)$.

I am asking about the proof of this result:

For every open set $B$ in $(0,1)$ we have $A∩B$ is not empty

Comment: How are you defining "dense"?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @lulu: see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set

Comment: And, can you see where that reference says "A has non-empty intersection with every non-empty open subset of X" as a formal definition of the density of set $A$?  Note:  You left "non-empty" out of your statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. A dense set by definition is such that for every point $x$ in $(0,1)$ and any $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $a\in A$ such that $d(x,a)<\epsilon$. If now $B$ is open (and not empty), then $B$ contains an interval, and therefore the intersection with $A$ is also not empty.